# How to run a method before all test in word spec like unit test?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

How can I run a before method with word spec like in scala?
I have this code, but the before method is not executing before my test:

```
class SomeClassTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test", ConfigFactory.empty())) with WordSpecLike with MockitoSugar with BeforeAndAfter {

override protected def before(fun: => Any): Unit = {
  //some code ...
}

"A SomeClass" must {
  "blah blah blah" in {
    //some code...
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to actually override `before` in `SomeClassTest`, but instead call it passing a function with test setup code:

```
class SomeClassTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test", ConfigFactory.empty())) with WordSpecLike with MockitoSugar with BeforeAndAfter {

  before {
    //some code ...
  }

  "A SomeClass" must {
    "blah blah blah" in {
      //some code...
    }
  }

}
```